# base R & data.table: group, filter, then aggregate

Tags: r, data.table

There is an example on this blog (not affiliated):

> https://www.sumsar.net/blog/pandas-feels-clunky-when-coming-from-r/

comparing R (tidyverse) and python (pandas) for data manipulation (group, filter,
summarize).

The minimal example is a table with three columns: `country`, `amount`, `discount`
and 2-3 observations/rows per country.

dput:

```
structure(list(country = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "UK", "UK", "UK", "France", "France", "France", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Japan", 
"Japan", "Japan", "India", "India", "India", "Brazil", "Brazil"
), amount = c(2000L, 3500L, 3000L, 120L, 180L, 3100L, 130L, 160L, 
190L, 110L, 170L, 220L, 140L, 200L, 230L, 150L, 210L, 240L, 160L, 
220L, 250L, 170L, 230L, 260L, 180L, 240L, 270L, 190L, 250L, 280L, 
200L, 260L), discount = c(10L, 15L, 20L, 12L, 18L, 21L, 13L, 
16L, 19L, 11L, 17L, 22L, 14L, 20L, 23L, 15L, 21L, 24L, 16L, 22L, 
25L, 17L, 23L, 26L, 18L, 24L, 27L, 19L, 25L, 28L, 20L, 26L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

the idea is to group by `country` than filter all rows that have `amount` <= median(`amount`)*10. And then calculate total = `amount` - `discount`

In dplyr API this looks like this:

```
purchases |>
  group_by(country) |>                     
  filter(amount <= median(amount) * 10) |> 
  summarize(total = sum(amount - discount))
```

where the sequence of grouping and filtering is critical due to two edge cases USA, and Canada:
(correctly:)

```
1 Canada    270
2 USA      8455
```

If we don't filter at all the total would be the same for all countries except canada;

```
1 Canada   3349
2 USA      8455
```

and if we would filter before grouping, the result would be correct for all countries except USA.

```
1 Canada    270
2 USA      1990
```

Using base R `by` i can reproduce the correct result:

```
purchases|>
  by(
    country,
    \(x) sum(x$amount[x$amount <= median(x$amount)*10]-x$discount[x$amount <= median(x$amount)*10])
    )
```

but it is useless due to the output format.

Using aggregate i can only reproduce the example where the filter is not `country` specific:

```
aggregate(
  amount - discount ~ country,
  data = purchases,
  FUN = sum,
  subset = amount <= median(amount)*10
)
```

i,e USA has the wrong total value 1990.

and using `data.table` I am able to get the correct result,

```
purchases[,.(total = sum(amount[amount <= median(amount)*10] - discount[amount <= median(amount)*10])), country][order(country)]
```

but only if I apply the subset/filter/logical index on both columns: `amount` and `discount`;
which should be avoided imo, because it is repetitive, and potentially error prone.

So ultimately my question is:

###### how to perform group based subsets prior aggregation in baseR, and in proper data.table style?

Comment: You shouldn't try to cram everything into one function. With base R you can achieve this with a `transform` and `ave`, then a `subset`, then an `aggregate`. In `data.table` you can do this more naturally using 2 bracketed expresssions, not one. Just like in `dplyr` you use `group_by` then `filter` and then `summarize`.

Comment: valid points, i still miss out on some base essentials s.a. ave and transform, they are essential to move from dplyr to base. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

My `data.table` is a little rusty, but I would maybe do this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[, cond := amount <= median(amount) * 10, by = country][
  (cond), .(total = sum(amount - discount)), by = country
]
#       country total
#  1:       USA  8455
#  2:    Canada   270
#  3:        UK   432
#  4:    France   450
#  5:   Germany   513
#  6: Australia   540
#  7:     Italy   567
#  8:     Spain   594
#  9:     Japan   621
# 10:     India   648
# 11:    Brazil   414
```

And with base R:

```
transform(df, threshold = ave(x = amount, country, FUN = median) * 10) |>
  subset(amount <= threshold) |>
  aggregate(amount - discount ~ country, data = _, FUN = sum)
#      country amount - discount
# 1  Australia               540
# 2     Brazil               414
# 3     Canada               270
# 4     France               450
# 5    Germany               513
# 6      India               648
# 7      Italy               567
# 8      Japan               621
# 9      Spain               594
# 10        UK               432
# 11       USA              8455
```

Comment: Thanks solid answers, how does the := operator work or how is called?

Comment: It's data.table's internal assignment operator for creating new columns by reference. See it's help page at `?":="` or read an introduction to `data.table` for examples.

Answer (score 4):

In base R we can use this:

```
purchases |>
 transform(median = ave(amount, country, FUN = median),
           total = amount - discount) |>
 subset(amount <= 10 * median) |>
 aggregate(total ~ country, data = _, FUN = sum)
```

giving

```
     country total
1  Australia   540
2     Brazil   414
3     Canada   270
4     France   450
5    Germany   513
6      India   648
7      Italy   567
8      Japan   621
9      Spain   594
10        UK   432
11       USA  8455
```

To use `by` note that piping the `by` code from the question into `stack()` would turn its output into a data frame.  Here we do that and make some improvements.  We define function `Stack` to be like `stack` except the columns are reversed so that the country column is first and a `names=` argument allows specification of the two column names.

```
Stack <- function(x, names) stack(x)[2:1] |> setNames(names)

purchases |>
  by(purchases$country, \(x) x |>
      subset(amount <= 10 * median(amount)) |>
      with(sum(amount - discount))
   ) |>
  Stack(c("country", "total"))
```

Comment: very explicit solution, unfortunatly it didnt work for me i got an Error: unexpected input from the aggregate i guess. What is your R version?

Comment: found it the _ is only available R.Version >= 4.2

Answer (score 4):

Yet another `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[,.(total = sum((amount - discount)[amount <= median(amount)*10])), country]
#>       country total
#>  1:       USA  8455
#>  2:    Canada   270
#>  3:        UK   432
#>  4:    France   450
#>  5:   Germany   513
#>  6: Australia   540
#>  7:     Italy   567
#>  8:     Spain   594
#>  9:     Japan   621
#> 10:     India   648
#> 11:    Brazil   414
```

Performing the operation in a single step and avoiding `.SD` (which is slow in a grouping operation) is somewhat faster:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Gregor = dt[, cond := amount <= median(amount) * 10, by = country][
    (cond), .(total = sum(amount - discount)), by = country
  ],
  thelatemail = dt[, 
            .SD[amount <= median(amount) * 10, .(total = sum(amount - discount))],
            by=country
  ],
  jblood94 = setDT(dt)[,.(total = sum((amount - discount)[amount <= median(amount)*10])), country],
  check = "identical"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>         expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#>       Gregor  894.1  936.1 1075.930 1007.95 1132.85 3907.7   100
#>  thelatemail 3570.1 3934.5 4451.737 4159.85 4561.65 8518.9   100
#>     jblood94  571.2  617.3  674.327  660.20  725.35  887.2   100
```

Comment: That's clever stuff.

Comment: very nice solution, shifting the [amount <= median(amount)*10] outside the parentheses works  as intended, should have come up with that one myself, also thanks for the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of one option in *data.table* code which would reduce the repetitiveness:

Using `.SD` to access the sub-data.table inside each `country` group:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(purchases)
purchases[, 
    .SD[amount <= median(amount) * 10, .(total = sum(amount - discount))],
    by=country
]

#      country total
#       <char> <int>
# 1:       USA  8455
# 2:    Canada   270
# 3:        UK   432
# 4:    France   450
# 5:   Germany   513
# 6: Australia   540
# 7:     Italy   567
# 8:     Spain   594
# 9:     Japan   621
#10:     India   648
#11:    Brazil   414
```

And an additional `aggregate` method, using the `subset=` argument to do the subsetting inline:

```
aggregate(
    cbind(total = amount - discount) ~ country,
    data=purchases,
    FUN=sum,
    subset=as.logical(ave(amount, country, FUN=\(x) x <= median(x) * 10))
)

#     country total
#1  Australia   540
#2     Brazil   414
#3     Canada   270
#4     France   450
#5    Germany   513
#6      India   648
#7      Italy   567
#8      Japan   621
#9      Spain   594
#10        UK   432
#11       USA  8455
```

I've always thought `by()` is also very close to being useful in the modern R world, just with a few tweaks to take care of common use cases. It's remarkable how flexible the function actually is, in that it can do what `mutate`, `summarise`, `transmute` etc all do in a functional way (just a bit slowly and a bit more clunkily!). E.g.:

```
dcrby <- function(...) do.call(rbind, by(...))
ofun <- function(x, var, out, row=1) cbind(x[row, var, drop=FALSE], out)

var <- "country"
dcrby(purchases, purchases[var], FUN=\(x) {
    x <- x[x$amount <= median(x$amount) * 10,]
    ofun(x, var, list(total=sum(x$amount - x$discount)))
})

##            country total
##Australia Australia   540
##Brazil       Brazil   414
##Canada       Canada   270
##France       France   450
##Germany     Germany   513
##India         India   648
##Italy         Italy   567
##Japan         Japan   621
##Spain         Spain   594
##UK               UK   432
##USA             USA  8455
```

Comment: I think .SD is a good idea if going for readability, ever if not as performant as @jbloods94 's   method. The ave function i didn't know yet, seems i missed this and its needed to make the base R toolchain complete.